# Android debugger does not work on my mac, freezes when it is trying to connect to port 8601

Tags: android, debugging

I just got a mac and trying to set up my android development.  I cannot get the debugger to run, when I look at the log I see the last line is

[2011-11-08 12:23:39 - test2] Attempting to connect debugger to 'org.test' on port 8601
I'm assuming it connect connect to that port?
Ted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you have marked you app as debbugeable?

In Eclipse, you can do this from the Application tab when viewing the Manifest (on the right side, set Debuggable to true). Otherwise, in the AndroidManifest.xml file, add android:debuggable="true" to the  element.

do you turned on USB debbuging in your device?

Turn on "USB Debugging" on your device.
On the device, go to Settings > Applications > Development and enable USB debugging (on an Android 4.0 device, the setting is located in Settings > Developer options).

and the last, some devices require  the android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP permission set in its manifest file in order to debug the app. try this:

```
 <manifest>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP"></uses-permission>
 </manifest>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your time in posting your comment, I added the line to the menafest file, did not work.  I endded up re-installing eclipse, now it works, but it does not work with the old work space,